# how to fix pg_query(): Query failed ERROR: syntax error at or near while inserting data using php

Tags: php, postgresql-9.6

I have a script that is supposed to insert username, email and comment_value which are varchar in a table named user using Postgres. On clicking the submit button I got this error:

> Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou
>   près de « user » LINE 1: INSERT INTO
>   user(username,email,comment_value) VALUES( ^ in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tourist_admin\contact\commentaire.php on line 14

NB: there's a fourth attribute named admin_confirmation which can be null and will be completed by the admin during editing so i didn't include it in the insert query.

My code;

```html
<?php
 
 $db = pg_connect( "host = localhost port = 5432  dbname = essaouira_tourisme user = postgres password = 0000");

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $comment_value = $_POST['comment_value'];

  if ($username && $email && $comment_value) {

   $query = "INSERT INTO user(username,email,comment_value) VALUES(
   '".$username."','".$email."','".$comment_value."')";
   $result = pg_query($db,$query);

   if ($result) {
    echo "<h2 color = 'red'>Votre commentaire a été enregistré avec succès</h2>";
   }

  }
  else{
   echo "veuillez remplir tous les champs";
  }

 }
 ?>
<html>
   <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Contact Form Design</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="contact-title">
  <h2>vos commentaires nous seront utiles</h2>
  <h1>Donnez vos avis</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="contact-form">
  <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="commentaire.php">
   <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="votre pseudo" required><br>

   <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="votre courriel" required><br>

   <textarea name="comment_value" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="votre commentaire ici" required></textarea><br>

   <input type="submit" class="form-control submit"  name= "submit" value="ENVOYER">
  </form>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`user` is a reserved word. You will need to use back ticks around the table name to be able to use a table named user.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username,email,comment_value) VALUES(
        '".$username."','".$email."','".$comment_value."')";
```

Comment: even i use  ticks around the user table i got the same error but by renaming the user table into  comment_user it works. so thank you @Dave